# dColumns returning Nan with dictionary mapping

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data frame that looks like below:

```
         City         State              Country
      Chicago            IL        United States
       Boston                    
    San Diego            CA        United States
  Los Angeles            CA        United States
San Francisco
   Sacramento     
    Vancouver            BC               Canada
      Toronto
```

I have 3 lists that contain all the missing values:

```
city_list = ['Boston', 'San Francisco', 'Sacramento', 'Toronto']
state_list = ['MA', 'CA', 'CA', 'ON']
country_list = ['United States', 'United States', 'United States', 'Canada']
```

And here's my ideal result:

```
         City         State              Country
      Chicago            IL        United States
       Boston            MA        United States
    San Diego            CA        United States
  Los Angeles            CA        United States
San Francisco            CA        United States
   Sacramento            CA        United States
    Vancouver            BC               Canada
      Toronto            ON               Canada
```

I used a potential method that's suggested by a helpful person, but I've been scratching my head and couldn't figure out what went wrong. And here's the code:

```
state_dict = dict(zip(city_list, state_list))
country_dict = dict(zip(city_list, country_list))
df = df.set_index('City')
df['State'] = df['State'].map(state_dict)
df['Country'] = df['Country'].map(country_dict)
df.reset_index()
print(df.City, df.State, df.Country)
```

But every cell of the State and Country columns return NaN.

```
         City         State         Country
      Chicago           NaN             NaN
       Boston           NaN             NaN
    San Diego           NaN             NaN
  Los Angeles           NaN             NaN
San Francisco           NaN             NaN
   Sacramento           NaN             NaN
    Vancouver           NaN             NaN
      Toronto           NaN             NaN
```

What went wrong here? And how would you change the code? Thanks.

Comment: :hmm.jpg: try this: `df['City'] = df['City'].str.strip(); df = df.set_index('City')` and then the rest of the code.

Comment: I tried, still didn't work. But the answer below worked. Thank you anyway, you are very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that map should be called on the 'City' rather than 'State' field, like so:

```
df['State'] = df['City'].map(state_dict)
```

However, this has the problem that it overwrites any original 'State' values for cities which are not in your dictionary - e.g. 'Chicago'. One solution that gets around this is the following syntactically clumsier (but I believe correct) code:

```
df['State'] = df.apply(lambda x: state_dict[x['City']] if x['City'] in state_dict else x['State'], axis=1)
```

And it'll be the same idea for the country field.

I should add that this only works if you do not first set 'City' as index as you have in your example.

Comment: Oh yes!!!! It works!!! Yea I also thought about that too, that not all the values are mapped in the dictionary, but I wasn't sure. And yes, thank you SO MUCH!!! You just solved the problem I had for the past 2 days. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Yea I tried it, I got an error of `('City', 'occurred at index Chicago')`, then I removed that `set_index` line and it solved everything! Thanks again, really appreciated!